# how to get data from post request in express\nodeJS and redirect user to html file after submit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i just red this [post](http://www.hacksparrow.com/post-get-request-handling-in-node-js-express.html)

my express Code is

```
var express= require('express');
var app= express();
var path= require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))) //one way to server file
//app.use(express.static(__dirname,'/public'));

app.get('/',function(request, response){
    response.send("responde send");



})
app.get('/userName',function(request, response){
    response.send(request.query["userName"]);

})
app.post('/userName1',function(request,response){
    response.send(request.body.userName);
    console.log(request.body['userName']);

})



var server= app.listen(3001,function(){
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
console.log("listening "+port+ "port while the host"+host);
})
```

now handling get request using this code
html is

```
<form action="/userName" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="userName">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

for post request my html is

```
<form action="/userName1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

but the problem how to get post request data??
i have tried these two line

```
 response.send(request.body.userName);
 console.log(request.body['userName']);
```

but not working while this [link code is same](http://www.hacksparrow.com/post-get-request-handling-in-node-js-express.html) where i am learning.
Also inform me how to redirect user to any html file when user submit a form?

Answer (score 1):

That link is outdated. ExpressJS now uses body parser as a [separate component](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), which is what you need in order to parse form data properly.

As for redirection, you could use javascript:

```
window.location = "https://www.google.com"
```

or, set the redirect header on the server:

```
res.setHeader("Location", "http://somewhere.com")
```

which is the same as:

```
res.location("http://somewhere.com")
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :( Can you reformulate your sentence?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. window.location can be use with html file? which is inside of my project root directory. you specified url direct for redirection, i want to serve html file on submit click

Answer (score 0):

what I use is Body-Parser with Express 4. So you need to assign Body-Parser to Express, and then, you can do something like:

```
app.post("userName1", function(req, res){

  var username = req.body.userName;

});
```

Is in bold method used, path the information is sent, name of the input of the form sent respectively.

As for redirection, you can use: res.redirect("URL"), or:

```
res.send("<script> JAVASCRIPT REDIRECT CODE </script>")
```

Hope It works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  Like below

```
    res.send("<script> window.location = 'http://localhost:8080'; </script>");
```

Above code is working for me. Hope also for you.